# Custom aspx page's (i think layouts page or maybe application page) master page not setting properly

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I added a custom aspx page, it works but my custom master page is not being applied.

My master page resides in site collection only, so I am trying this flag to custom aspx page,

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddBlue.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyWeb.AddBlue"
 MasterPageFile="~/sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/masterpages/mycustom.master" %>
```

But I am getting this error,

> The file
>   '/_layouts/15/MyWeb/~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/masterpages/mycustom.master'
>   does not exist.

Comment: are you add custom page via SharePoint Designer ?or via visual studio ?

Comment: if SPD Remove this MasterPageFile="~/sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/masterpages/mycustom.master" then manually write MasterPageFile=" here you should find PickUp url select the correct path of masterpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue by adding

DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/custom.master"

Then we have to set CustomMasterUrl of web where this page will be called from, then regardless of what masterpage your web have... this custom page will use that.